# Ordinary Data Processing Task in Haskell: Vague Misgivings

Tags: haskell, homework

This is an ordinary data processing task: read a list of dates and amounts (for example, deposits and withdrawals from a bank account) and report the date on which the lowest balance was recorded and what that balance was. While I do get the correct answer--always a virtue--with the code below, I can't help thinking that it could be done better (e.g. more concisely). I've included the preliminary input parsing code so that the whole thing can be compiled and run as is.

```
module Main where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Data.Time
import Numeric
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>), (*>))
import Control.Monad.State as CM

--The purpose is to sum up a list of dated values (example: transactions in a bank
--account) and produce the date and amount of the lowest recorded balance.
--For the three lines below, the output would be: 
--     DtdBal {runningBal = 4859.96, lowDt = 2013-01-23, lowBal = 4859.96} 

--12/1/12,  6844.79
--1/1/13,   992.41
--1/23/13,  -2977.24

data DtdVal = DtdVal { dt :: Day
                     , amt :: Double 
                     } deriving Show

data DtdBal = DtdBal { runningBal :: Double
                     , lowDt :: Day
                     , lowBal :: Double
                     } deriving Show

main = do res <- parseFromFile sched "escrow.txt"
          case res of 
            Right l -> putStrLn . show $ process l
            Left _ -> error "Oops"
    where process (x:xs) = execState (minBal xs) (initState x) 
          initState x = DtdBal { runningBal = amt x, lowDt = dt x, lowBal = amt x }

minBal :: [DtdVal] -> CM.State DtdBal ()
minBal [] = return ()
minBal (x:xs) = do
  rBal <- runningBal <$> get
  lBal <- lowBal <$> get
  lDt  <- lowDt <$> get
  if amt x + rBal < lBal 
     then put $ DtdBal { runningBal = rBal + amt x, lowDt = dt x, lowBal = amt x + rBal}
     else put $ DtdBal { runningBal = rBal + amt x, lowDt = lDt, lowBal = lBal }
  minBal xs

sched :: CharParser () [DtdVal]        
sched = line `endBy` newline

line :: CharParser () DtdVal
line = DtdVal <$> dts <*> (char ',' >> spaces *> readSgnd)

dts :: CharParser () Day
dts = toDay <$> many digit `sepBy` char '/'
    where toDay [x, y, z] = fromGregorian (2000 + read z) (read x) (read y)

readSgnd :: CharParser () Double
readSgnd = do
  optional (char '+')
  inp <- getInput
  let [(num, inp')] = readSigned readFloat inp
  setInput inp'
  return num
```

Answer (score 2):

- recursive part of `minBal` is `mapM_`
- multiple `get` is better to refactor into one
- `get` - process - `put` part of `minBal` is `modify`
- state monad is not necessary - you can use plain `foldr` instead of `mapM_` and `modify`
- `runningBal` is better to implement using `scanr`. Then `zip` running balances and source list and `foldr` the resulting list of tuples
- use `minimum` to find the minimum

Here is a more idiomatic approach to minBal:

```
runningBal' = scanl1 (+) . map amt

rb l = zip (runningBal' l) l

mb l = minimumBy (compare `on` fst) l

minDay = mb . rb

minBal' l = DtdBal { 
    runningBal = fst $ last runningBals, 
    lowDt = dt $ snd md, 
    lowBal = fst md } 
    where
        runningBals = rb l
        md = minDay l
```

You can inline all the small functions for the final code but that's the order I created them in. Note that `rb` is calculated twice, but I was not sure if you really need the final balance. In your algorithm it was a byproduct.

`main` can be rewritten too:

```
main' = (parseFromFile sched >=> process >=> print) "escrow.txt" where
    process (Right l) = return $ minBal' l
    process (Left _) = error "Oops"
```

Basically, `putStrLn . show` is `print` and composition is your friend. `>=>` is monadic variant of `.`. It's advantage over `>>=` is associativity - it lets you refactor your code more easily.

Here is a shorter version of `minBal'` which also saves a few calculations, but `last` is still `O(N)`:

```
minBal' l = DtdBal { 
    runningBal = last runningBals, 
    lowDt = dt $ snd md, 
    lowBal = fst md } 
    where
        md = minimumBy (compare `on` fst) $ zip runningBals l
        runningBals = scanl1 (+) $ map amt l
```

Let me know how this works for very large files.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no need to use a state monad for the `minBal`, a simple
  `foldl` suffices.
- One nice thing about using a parser library is that it will automatically
  generate some helpful error messages, but the way it is used in `dts` will   only give a pattern match failure if something is wrong. Similarly a less helpful error message will be generated from a parse failure using `readSigned`.
- It is not uncommon to simply name the parser from the thing that is being parsed, similar to BNF grammars.

```hs
data Transaction = Transaction 
  { time :: Day
  , amount :: Double 
  } deriving Show

data DtdBal = DtdBal
  { runningBal :: Double
  , lowDt :: Day
  , lowBal :: Double
  } deriving Show

main = do  
  result <- parseFromFile transactions "escrow.txt"
  case result of 
    Right ls -> print . minBal  $ ls
    Left e -> print e

minBal (l:ls) = foldl go start ls
  where
    start = DtdBal{runningBal = amount l,lowDt = time l,lowBal = amount l}
    go a b
      | newBal < lowBal a = a{runningBal = newBal,lowBal = newBal,lowDt = time b}
      | otherwise         = a{runningBal = newBal}
      where newBal = amount b + runningBal a

transactions :: CharParser () [Transaction]        
transactions = transaction `endBy` newline

transaction :: CharParser () Transaction
transaction = Transaction <$> date <*> (char ',' >> spaces *> float)

date :: CharParser () Day
date = do 
  x <- int
  char '/'
  y <- int
  char '/'
  z <- int
  return (fromGregorian (2000 + z) x y)

int :: (Integral a) => CharParser () a
int = (fromInteger . read) <$> many digit

float :: CharParser () Double
float =
  (char '-' >> negate <$> posFloat) <|>
  (optional (char '+') >> posFloat)
  where
   posFloat = do
     x <- many digit
     char '.'
     y <- many digit
     return (read (x ++ ('.':y)))
```